# Getting datatable to work with highcharter in flexdashboards

Tags: r, highcharts, dt, flexdashboard

I'm building an R flexdashboard, I'm after using *datatable* and *highcharter* in the same dashboard. It appears that as soon as I include highcharter the datatable no longer functions correctly, i.e. I can't scroll vertically and no scroll bars appear.

Hopefully some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
library(DT)

```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
datatable(iris)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart C

```{r}
x <- c(rnorm(10000), rnorm(1000, 4, 0.5))

hchart(x, name = "data") 
```
````

**To make the datatbale then work, just comment out the highchart:**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
library(DT)

```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
datatable(iris)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart C

```{r}
# x <- c(rnorm(10000), rnorm(1000, 4, 0.5))
# 
# hchart(x, name = "data") 
```
````

This isn't working when I knit the document. I've done a fair bit of googling and there are some posts about the scroll not working, but not sure if there is an error with highcharter and datatable specifically.

My session info:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.1         highcharter_0.8.2   DT_0.15             flexdashboard_0.5.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5        compiler_4.0.2    pillar_1.4.6      xts_0.12-0        tools_4.0.2      
 [6] digest_0.6.25     packrat_0.5.0     lattice_0.20-41   jsonlite_1.7.0    lubridate_1.7.9  
[11] evaluate_0.14     lifecycle_0.2.0   tibble_3.0.3      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.7      
[16] igraph_1.2.5      rstudioapi_0.11   crosstalk_1.1.0.1 curl_4.3          yaml_2.2.1       
[21] xfun_0.16         stringr_1.4.0     knitr_1.29        generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.3.2      
[26] htmlwidgets_1.5.1 grid_4.0.2        tidyselect_1.1.0  data.table_1.13.0 glue_1.4.1       
[31] R6_2.4.1          rmarkdown_2.3     TTR_0.23-6        purrr_0.3.4       tidyr_1.1.1      
[36] magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.7   htmltools_0.5.0   ellipsis_0.3.1    rsconnect_0.8.16 
[41] rlist_0.4.6.1     assertthat_0.2.1  quantmod_0.4.17   tinytex_0.25      stringi_1.4.6    
[46] broom_0.7.0       crayon_1.3.4      zoo_1.8-8
```

Comment: I don't have any issues. I do both of your code chunks and I get scrolling capabilities with the Datatable. I am on a mac using Firefox web browser

Comment: Thank you, it might well be browser based, within my organisation I'm stuck using this with IE, shocking I know.